# Restful Web Service - Error in @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

Tags: rest

I tried to create a simple Restful Web Service, but when I tried to debug it, an error occurred when the "return customer" like the picture. May I know what is the cause? It seem like it failed Convert a Java Object to XML using JAXB when return object Customer which contain data.

```
package com.mkyong.rest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/xml/customer")
public class XMLService {

@GET
@Path("/{pin}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Customer getCustomerInXML(@PathParam("pin") int pin) {

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setName("mkyong");
    customer.setPin(pin);

    return customer;

}
```

}

```
package com.mkyong.rest;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "pin"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    String name;
    int pin;

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getPin() {
        return pin;
    }

    public void setPin(int pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

}
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    Restful Web Application

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAVA API</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAVA API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

[image]

Comment: I have found the error in this sample, the latest eclipse IDE had deprecated the xml jar, you have to add it back manually in the IDE when running and debugging (in the configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error in this sample, the latest eclipse IDE had deprecated the xml jar, you have to add it back manually in the IDE when running and debugging (in the configuration) –